# What is the space complexity of my TwoSum algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def twoNumberSum(array, targetSum):
    # Write your code here.
    for i in array:
        if targetSum-i in array and  targetSum-i != i:
            return [i, targetSum-i]
    return []
```

Comment: I didn't assign a dictionary to the function

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity is `O(n^2)` which can be reduced to `O(n)` if you convert the array(python list) to a set
The space complexity is Constant here.

```
def twoNumberSum(array, targetSum):
    # Write your code here.
    for i in array: # O(N)
        if targetSum-i in array and  targetSum-i != I: # O(N) because of `in` operator
            return [i, targetSum-i]
    return []
```

Use Set. The time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is also O(n)

```
def twoNumberSum(array, targetSum):
    # Write your code here.
    set_arrary = set(array)
    for i in array:# O(N)
        if targetSum-i in set_arrary and  targetSum-i != i: #O(1) 
            return [i, targetSum-i]
    return []
```

Comment: `in` operator also performs linear search and that why it is O(n^2). Space complexity for your code is constant and for my approach using set is O(n)

Comment: Thanks! But what about the space complexity?